# For what complex $z$ does $f(z) = \frac12((-1+i\sqrt{3})z+(-2\sqrt{3}-18i))$ represent a rotation around $c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> The function
> $$f(z) = \frac{(-1 + i \sqrt{3}) z + (-2 \sqrt{3} - 18i)}{2}$$
> represents a rotation around some complex number $c$. Find $c$.

I don't know how to proceed, help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: A rotation around $c$ maps $c$ into itself. Therefore, solve the equation $f(c)=c$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* A rotation around $c$ is given by $(z-c)w+c$. Compare this is $f(z)=az+b$ to find $w$ and $c$.

Comment: The clever suggestion by @Stinking Bishop avoids finding $w$.

Comment: what does w represent in this case? is it the angle of rotation?